sql\queries\users.sql:1:1: relation "users" does not exist
I encountered this error when I ran the command “sqlc generate”, this is the structure of the sql and yaml files.
yaml and sql files structure
Relevant log output
PS C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\project_1> sqlc generate
# package 
sql\queries\users.sql:1:1: relation "users" does not exist

Database schema
-- +goose up

CREATE TABLE users (
     id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
     created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
     updated_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
     name TEXT NOT NULL
);

-- +goose down

DROP TABLE USERS;

SQL queries
-- name: CreateUser :one
INSERT INTO users (id, created_at, updated_at, name)
VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
RETURNING *;

Configuration
version: "2"
sql:
  - schema: "sql/schema"
    queries: "sql/queries"
    engine: "postgresql"
    gen:
      go:
        out: "internal/database"

Tried

Changing files and folders structure
Renaming files and queries
Checking for similar questions

Expected

No output in the terminal
"internal" folder creation with "database" subfolder and go code


The db schema needs capital letter on "Up" and "Down"
-- +goose Up
...
-- +goose Down
...

